# Python fabric "local" function does not respect environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: python, django, deployment, fabric

I have the following scheme for my project's settings:

```
myproject/
   app1/
   app2/
   appN/
   settings/
      __init__.py
      base.py
      devel.py
      production.py
```

In my local environment I have inside the virtualenvwrapper's `postactivate` script:

```
myproject_root=/home/rantanplan/Projects/repos/myproject
cd $myproject_root
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings.devel
```

So that when I do `workon myproject` it will change to the project's root dir and
set the active `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` I want.

This is fine for django and all the commands(like `python manage.py syncdb`) work.

Now on the other hand I have this fabric task:

```
@task
def syncdb():
    local('python manage.py syncdb --noinput')
```

This used to work fine when I had a simple `settings.py` file, but when I changed
to the above scheme it raises this exception:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'python manage.py syncdb --noinput'

Aborting.
```

Some additional notes:

- [project](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/api/contrib/django.html#fabric.contrib.django.project) function is not applicable here since it falsely assumes(internally) that all django settings modules are named as "settings".
- I tried the [settings_module](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/api/contrib/django.html#fabric.contrib.django.settings_module) function to no avail. It uses `os.environ` internally to set the environment variable but to no effect.
- If I print the `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']` just before my task definition, it correctly prints "myproject.settings.devel".

So what am I doing wrong here and how do you propose I should go about solving this issue?

---

To spare you the trouble I should say that I know I can solve this by doing:

```
def syncdb():
    with prefix('export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings.devel'):
        local('python manage.py syncdb --noinput')
```

but I'd rather avoid the use of `prefix` if I can.

Also I know I could do, as hynekcer suggests:

```
@task
def syncdb():
    local('python manage.py syncdb --settings=myproject.settings.devel --noinput')
```

but I really want to know why `local` does not respect the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and
why `settings_module` does not work as advertised.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and settings_module works for me. Do you use Django 1.4? Can you reproduce it on different machine?

Comment: @hynekcer When you say you can't reproduce the problem, I take it that you have a similar `settings` scheme as me and not a simple `settings.py`? And yes I have django 1.4 and the latest pip installable fabric.

Comment: Yes, the configuration `myproject/settings/anyfile.py`, an empty `myproject/settings/__init__.py` and the same fabfile.py like you.

Comment: @hynekcer Will try to reproduce on a different system and will get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the problem but I'm not sure what to make of it.

First of all it seems that I didn't reveal all the necessary bits of information.

Although my django project's structure is exactly as I described, my fabric
structure is a bit more complex.

In essence I follow some patterns from [this part of fabric's documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/usage/tasks.html#namespaces)

The complete structure is described below:

```
deployment/
  __init__.py
  fabric/
    __init__.py
    database.py
    repo.py
    services.py
myproject/
  app1/
  app2/
  appN/
manage.py
fabfile.py
```

Inside the `deployment/fabric/database.py` I had this code:

```
django.settings_module('myproject.settings.devel')

@task
def syncdb():
    local('python manage.py syncdb --noinput')
```

And inside my `fabfile.py` I had all my imports:

```
from deployment.fabric.database import dropdb, createdb, syncdb, createuser
from deployment.fabric.something import blahblah
```

For some reason, that I can't seem to grasp right now, inside the `fabfile.py`
the setting of the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`(which was happening inside the deployment/fabric/database.py) is not retained.

At first I came to the false realization that `os.environ` actions do not persist
across modules! But this is not true, as I immediately constructed a similar scenario
outside my django project and invalidated my false premise.

Then I checked fabric's `local` function and saw that it essentially is a wrapper
over `subprocess.Popen('...', shell=True)`. So I tested my previous experiment
with `subprocess.Popen` and it still retained the environment variables across modules.

I don't know if it has to do with fabric's magic tasks import or there is something
fundamental I don't grasp but any of the below methods will solve the issue.

**1)** Use the `prefix` context manager

```
def syncdb():
    with prefix('export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings.devel'):
        local('python manage.py syncdb --noinput')
```

**2)** Append a `--settings` value in the `local` command (as described by hynekcer)

```
@task
def syncdb():
    local('python manage.py syncdb --settings=myproject.settings.devel --noinput')
```

**3)** Include the `settings_module` call inside the task(Although it kinda invalidates its purpose).

```
@task
def syncdb():
    django.settings_module('myproject.settings.devel')
    local('python manage.py syncdb --noinput')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `settings` option. It has precedence over DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable.

```
@task
def syncdb():
    local('python manage.py syncdb --settings=myproject.settings.devel --noinput')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know I could do that and I will update my question to reflect that. But basically I want to know what is really going on with the `local` function and also why the `settings_module` function does not work as advertised. Either I'm doing something wrong or it has a bug.

Comment: Read my answer for more details. I upvote your answer as it is one of the ways to circumvent this issue.